# Updating the quantity of items in a shopping Cart not working properly

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django E-commerce Project, and I have been following a tutorial and afterwards I decided to redo it on my own without the tutorial but I am stuck in a small issue which I don't understand the logic behind it.

When a user adds an Item to Cart I want it to reflect on the no. of items that are showing on the navbar cart icon, but I am getting `Invalid filter: 'cart_item_count'`

Here is my Item model.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to=upload_design_to)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)
```

The application name is `store`, so here is what I have been done in the tutorial

Added a new folder in the app with the name of `templatetags` and inside the template tags folder created file called `cart_template_tags`
and here is what is inside it:

```
from django import template

from store.models import Order

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def cart_item_count(user):
    if user.is_authenticated:
        qs = Order.objects.filter(user=user, ordered=False)
        if qs.exists():
            return qs[0].items.count()
    return 0
```

My question is how do I fix this error and I want to understand behind the logic of having `cart_item_count` as a filter?

Is there an easier way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: try to restart the server.

Comment: @ha-neul nothing happened same error

Comment: do you have{% load cart_template_tags %} in your template?

Comment: @ha-neul yes you can add it as an answer thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to django doc about [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/), you need to

1. add `{% load cart_template_tags %}` in your template.
2. restart your server in order to get the custom-tags working.